# Optimize time when creating archive

Tags: find, tar, optimization

Currently I am using the following command to create an archive with files older than 7 days:

`find /var/tunningLog/ -type f -mtime +7 -print0 | tar -czf "/var/tunningLog/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz" --null -T - &&  echo "OK" || echo "NOK"`

But it is taking to long (currently `/var/tunningLog/` has 49G). Is there any way to speed up the process or to improve the command? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're creating your archive of `/var/TuningLog` in `/var/TuningLog`, the archive you create contains the archive you created a week ago, or earlier. You have an ever growing archive of archives.

Either modify your `find` to exclude your archives (`\! -name '*.tar.gz'`) if that doesn't exclude wanted files.

OR

Save your archives elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator, also I've replaced `find ... exec` with `find ...| xargs` and it had improved the execution time.

Comment: `xargs` and `tar` don't work together well. If you have too many filenames and `xargs` runs a second `tar -cvf ...`

Answer (score 0):

Using a `find | tar` pipe is something from the stoneage of UNIX when the only way to reuse code was to combine commands via pipelines.

This is slow because it requires to run `stat(2)` twice for every file.

- Once from within the `find(1)` command to identify the files of interest
- Another time from within `tar(1)` because tar needs the meta data for archiving

Since 33 years, there is another way to combine reusable code by using shared libraries and since 16 years, there is `libfind` that includes all features of the find command in a way that allows to reuse the functionality.

Since you are using non-standard `tar` options like `-T`, it seems that you are using `gtar` instead of `tar` and gtar is known for it's ineffective code for creating the tar headers.

I recommend you to have a look at `star`, the oldest free `tar` implementation that includes `libfind` support since 2005 and includes support for a `-find` option that permits to use `find(1)` syntax to the right side of `-find` on the command line.

Check e.g. the man page from the schilytools web page at: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html

This leads to a command line similar to:

```
star -c -f /tmp/xxx.tar -find . -type f -mtime +7
```

Comment: thanks for info  @schily